# What is the most efficient way to turn a list of directory path strings into a tree?

Tags: algorithms, trees

I'm trying to find out the most efficient way of turning a list of path strings into a hierarchical list of hash maps tree using these rules:

- Node labels are delimited/split by '/'
- Hash maps have the structure:

```
{
    label: "Node 0",
    children: []
}
```

- Node labels are also keys, so for example all nodes with the same label at the root level will be merged

So the following code:

```
[
    "Node 0/Node 0-0",
    "Node 0/Node 0-1",
    "Node 1/Node 1-0/Node 1-0-0"
]
```

Would turn into:

```
[
    {
        label: "Node 0",
        children: [
            {
                label: "Node 0-0",
                children: []
            },
            {
                label: "Node 0-1",
                children: []
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        label: "Node 1",
        children: [
            {
                label: "Node 1-0",
                children: [
                    {
                        label: "Node 1-0-0",
                        children: []
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: I don't understand what a "hierarchical list of hash maps tree" is.  I don't understand how the rules specify the desired output.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at the lexicographical order of your list of paths. It reveals a quite fast algorithm.